# Kentico 9 pagination and anchor links

Tags: kentico

I have a page with three webparts:

1. Pages Data Source
2. Basic Repeater
3. Universal Pager

Things are working as expected, but i was wonder if there is a way to scroll to the top of the Basic Repeater when a new page is selected. There isn't an anchor tag passed through the URL, just a parameter for the page selected. I've tried adding in an hash value to the QueryString, but that caused issues. Setting paging mode to PostBack cause the pagination to no longer work.

I've set paging mode to PostBack, and enabled Use update panel, all within the Universal Pager webpart. With this set, the repeater doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

What about *Reset scroll position* property in *Pager properties* section?

Comment: I tried that, didn't seem to work. I'm looking at a javascript solution. Jquery, .animate(). It may work.

Comment: I`ve already tried it and it works for me. You can also use javascript in transformation of pager and scroll to id of element (you can add it in content before/after of your repeater).

Comment: Having Reset scoll enabled dosn't do anything for me, odd. Are you using the pager properties in the repeater, or pagination webpart?

Comment: Universal pager with Repeater v9.0 without any HF

Comment: Thanks, time to start digging.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to anchor on every page change you can edit Page Transformation in Universal repeater. In there you can add anchor id to a link, but this will only work if you change **Paging mode** to **QueryString**.

Comment: thought about this, but i have another page that has multiple repeater/pagination combinations, so blanket change may have a domino effect.

Comment: but you can add Querystring key for every pager. Also Universal pages uses Target control name....